# Html divs not aligning vertically

Tags: javascript, html, layout, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to vertically align two Google Charts, one Bar Chart and one PieChart -> http://plnkr.co/edit/OtXFlav09r4WvoYC16X0?p=preview

Inside the body I have:

```
<body>
<div style="margin-left: 5px; width: 100%;">
  <d2 style="float: left;">
    <big>Oil Consumption - Barrels (from 1965)</big>
  </d2>
  <br />
  <br />
  <d2 style="float: left;">BP Statistical Review of World Energy, June 2015</d2>
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 20px;">
  <div id="div"></div>
  <div id="div1" "float:="" left;"=""></div>
</div>
```

but the two charts do not get aligned. Why?

> UPDATED CODE

```
<body>
<div style="margin-left: 5px; width: 100%;">
     <d1 style="float: left;"><big>Oil Consumption - Barrels (from 1965)</big></d1> <br><br>
     <d1 style="float: left;">BP Statistical Review of World Energy, June 2015</d1> <br><br>

</div>

   <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 20px;">
     <div id="div"></div>
     <div id="div1" style="float: left;"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: <div id="div1" style="float: left;"></div>

Comment: there is no tag such as d2

Comment: It doesn't work, I've updated my code...

Comment: <div id="div" style="float: left; width: 50%"></div>
      <div id="div1" style="float: left; width: 50%"></div>

Comment: also adjust the width in js

Comment: Now they overlap each other... by the way, in the post I meant that I want to  align them vertically, not horizontally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert in `pieOptions`

```
chartArea: {left:0,top:0}
```

and change values like you want

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MIFLJjZ1ka4YQPhiSzP4?p=preview)

Comment: Great answer, but now where is the title of the pie chart? It disappeared, I tried fixing the gap in between the charts but this seems to be not the case.

Comment: Nevermind! I just had to change your code into `chartArea: {left:0,top:20}`
Much apprish!